# pandas merge dataframes by closest time

Tags: pandas

I've got two dataframes (`logs` and `failures`), which I would like to merge so that I add in `logs` a column which has the value of the closest date found in 'failures'.

The code to generate `logs`, `failures`, and the desired `output` is below:

```
import pandas as pd
logs=pd.DataFrame({'date-time':pd.Series(['23/10/2015 10:20:54','22/10/2015 09:51:32','21/10/2015 06:51:32','28/10/2015 16:59:32','25/10/2015 04:41:32','24/10/2015 11:50:11']),'var1':pd.Series([0,1,3,1,2,4])})
logs['date-time']=pd.to_datetime(logs['date-time'])
failures=pd.DataFrame({'date':pd.Series(['23/10/2015 00:00:00','22/10/2015 00:00:00','21/10/2015 00:00:00']),'failure':pd.Series([1,1,1])})
failures['date']=pd.to_datetime(failures['date'])
output=pd.DataFrame({'date-time':pd.Series(['23/10/2015 10:20:54','22/10/2015 09:51:32','21/10/2015 06:51:32','28/10/2015 16:59:32','25/10/2015 04:41:32','24/10/2015 11:50:11']),'var1':pd.Series([0,1,3,1,2,4]),'closest_failure':pd.Series(['23/10/2015 00:00:00','22/10/2015 00:00:00','21/10/2015 00:00:00','23/10/2015 00:00:00','23/10/2015 00:00:00','23/10/2015 00:00:00'])})
output['date-time']=pd.to_datetime(output['date-time'])
```

Any ideas? The real dataset is very large, so efficiency is also a concern.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can reindex with method="nearest". There may be a neater way, but using a Series with the failure logs in the index and values works:

```
In [11]: failures_dt = pd.Series(failures["date"].values, failures["date"])

In [12]: failures_dt.reindex(logs["date-time"], method="nearest")
Out[12]:
date-time
2015-10-23 10:20:54   2015-10-23
2015-10-22 09:51:32   2015-10-22
2015-10-21 06:51:32   2015-10-21
2015-10-28 16:59:32   2015-10-23
2015-10-25 04:41:32   2015-10-23
2015-10-24 11:50:11   2015-10-23
dtype: datetime64[ns]

In [13]: logs["nearest"] = failures_dt.reindex(logs["date-time"], method="nearest").values

In [14]: logs
Out[14]:
            date-time  var1    nearest
0 2015-10-23 10:20:54     0 2015-10-23
1 2015-10-22 09:51:32     1 2015-10-22
2 2015-10-21 06:51:32     3 2015-10-21
3 2015-10-28 16:59:32     1 2015-10-23
4 2015-10-25 04:41:32     2 2015-10-23
5 2015-10-24 11:50:11     4 2015-10-23
```

Answer (score 19):

In Pandas >= 0.19.0 you can now use [`pandas.merge_asof`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.19.0/generated/pandas.merge_asof.html) to get near matches. With 0.19 you're limited to taking the most recent failure value before or at the log value. However [with 0.20](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.merge_asof.html#pandas.merge_asof) you can get the nearest in either direction.

> Perform an asof merge. This is similar to a left-join except that we
>   match on nearest key rather than equal keys.
>
> For each row in the left DataFrame, we select the last row in the
>   right DataFrame whose ‘on’ key is less than or equal to the left’s
>   key. Both DataFrames must be sorted by the key.

```
In [3]: failures.sort_values("date", inplace=True)

In [6]: logs2=pd.DataFrame({'date-time':pd.Series(['23/10/2015 10:20:54','22/10/2015 09:51:32','21/10/2015 06:51:32','28/10/2015 16:59:32','25/10/2015 04:41:32','24/10/2015 11:50
   ...: :11', "20/10/2015 01:02:03"]),'var1':pd.Series([0,1,3,1,2,4, 99])})
   ...: 

In [7]: logs2['date-time']=pd.to_datetime(logs2['date-time'])

In [8]: logs2.sort_values("date-time", inplace=True)

In [9]: logs2
Out[9]: 
            date-time  var1
6 2015-10-20 01:02:03    99
2 2015-10-21 06:51:32     3
1 2015-10-22 09:51:32     1
0 2015-10-23 10:20:54     0
5 2015-10-24 11:50:11     4
4 2015-10-25 04:41:32     2
3 2015-10-28 16:59:32     1

In [10]: pd.merge_asof(logs2, failures, left_on="date-time", right_on="date")
Out[10]: 
            date-time  var1       date  failure
0 2015-10-20 01:02:03    99        NaT      NaN
1 2015-10-21 06:51:32     3 2015-10-21      1.0
2 2015-10-22 09:51:32     1 2015-10-22      1.0
3 2015-10-23 10:20:54     0 2015-10-23      1.0
4 2015-10-24 11:50:11     4 2015-10-23      1.0
5 2015-10-25 04:41:32     2 2015-10-23      1.0
6 2015-10-28 16:59:32     1 2015-10-23      1.0

In [11]: pd.merge_asof(logs2, failures, left_on="date-time", right_on="date", direction="nearest")
Out[11]: 
            date-time  var1       date  failure
0 2015-10-20 01:02:03    99 2015-10-21        1
1 2015-10-21 06:51:32     3 2015-10-21        1
2 2015-10-22 09:51:32     1 2015-10-22        1
3 2015-10-23 10:20:54     0 2015-10-23        1
4 2015-10-24 11:50:11     4 2015-10-23        1
5 2015-10-25 04:41:32     2 2015-10-23        1
6 2015-10-28 16:59:32     1 2015-10-23        1
```