# Python merge two csv files on multiple columns and nearest datetime

Tags: python, csv, pandas, merge

I have two csv files which I would like to merge.

File1:

```
rel_id, acc_id, value, timestamp
1, 2, True, 2016-01-04 19:20:22
2, 3, True, 2016-01-04 18:35:56
1, 2, True, 2016-01-04 20:43:12
1, 5, False, 2016-01-04 18:15:20
2, 3, True, 2016-01-04 20:43:11
```

File2:

```
rel_id, acc_id, value, timestamp
1, 2, 250, 2016-01-04 20:43:13
1, 5, 610, 2016-01-04 18:15:23
2, 3, 400, 2016-01-04 18:35:58
2, 3, 300, 2016-01-04 20:43:13
1, 2, 500, 2016-01-04 19:20:23
```

I would like to merge the two files based on the rel_id, acc_id and timestamp.

Merged(file1 and file2):

```
rel_id, acc_id, value_file1, timestamp, value_file2
1, 2, True, 2016-01-04 19:20:22, 500
2, 3, True, 2016-01-04 18:35:56, 400
1, 2, True, 2016-01-04 20:43:12, 250
1, 5, False, 2016-01-04 18:15:20, 610
2, 3, True, 2016-01-04 20:43:11, 300
```

However the timestamp of file2 is slightly later in time.

Searching on stackoverflow lead me to this post: [pandas merge dataframes by closest time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33272807/pandas-merge-dataframes-by-closest-time)

But I have no idea how to approach the matching on rel_id, acc_id and timestamp nearest.

```
import pandas as pd


file1 = pd.read_csv('file1.csv')
file2 = pd.read_csv('file2.csv')


file1.columns = ['rel_id', 'acc_id', 'value', 'timestamp']
file2.columns = ['rel_id', 'acc_id', 'value', 'timestamp']


file1['timestamp'] = pd.to_datetime(file1['timestamp'])
file2['timestamp'] = pd.to_datetime(file2['timestamp'])


file1_dt = pd.Series(file1["timestamp"].values, file1["timestamp"])
file1_dt.reindex(file2["timestamp"], method="nearest")
file2["nearest"] = file1_dt.reindex(file2["timestamp"],    method="nearest").values

print file2
```

I tried above code based on the other post, but this doesn't match on rel_id and acc_id yet. Plus that above code already raise an error:

ValueError: index must be monotonic increasing or decreasing

Any help is highly appriciated. Thanks.

Comment: doesn't this always choose the file that is ahead of time? doesn't make a lot of sense, or I am misunderstanding something?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You're trying to reindex based in unsorted indices.
Assuming your CSV has no header:

```
column_names = ['rel_id', 'acc_id', 'value', 'timestamp']
file1 = pd.read_csv('file1.csv',
                    index_col=['timestamp'],
                    parse_dates='timestamp',
                    header=None,
                    names=column_names).sort_index()
file2 = pd.read_csv('file2.csv',
                    index_col=['timestamp'],
                    parse_dates='timestamp',
                    header=None,
                    names=column_names).sort_index()
file1.set_index(file1.reindex(file2.index, method='nearest').index, inplace=True)



                     rel_id  acc_id  value
timestamp
2016-01-04 18:15:23       1       5  False
2016-01-04 18:35:58       2       3   True
2016-01-04 19:20:23       1       2   True
2016-01-04 20:43:13       2       3   True
2016-01-04 20:43:13       1       2   True
```

And merge file1 and file2:

```
file1.reset_index().merge(file2.reset_index(), on=['acc_id', 'rel_id', 'timestamp']).set_index('timestamp')
```

Comment: thanks your answer and the example. I feel stupid, but how do I get the merged output (so showing both value columns and merge on either timestamp of file1 or file2)? When using `pd.merged(file1, file2, on='timestamp')` I will get an error.

Comment: Might be more convenient way to do it but something like: `file1.reset_index().merge(file2.reset_index(), on=['acc_id', 'rel_id', 'timestamp']).set_index('timestamp')`. Especially since now you're setting `timestamp` as the index, then resetting and setting it again...

Comment: Valtuarte: Thank you for the help. I can't seem to get it working in the right way yet. I edited my question by adding the desired output and change in file2 data to show that it's not always in chronological order. When using the suggested code in your comment it goes wrong at the timestamp of file2 at 2016-01-04 20:43:13. It is shows this timestamp 2 times for rel_id = 1 and acc_id = 2.

Comment: Thanks valtuarte. It does work with the sample data, therefore I checked your answer. However unfortunatly I can't get it working with my actual data .

Comment: setting the index to timestamp wouldn't work unless the timestamps are unique. since the goal is to merge on multiple columns, it is possible that the timestamps can be unique per rel_id, but may not be unique in the dataframe.