# Combine pandas Data Frames based on a condition?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, merge, append

Hi I have two dataframes like below: df_com and df_tra respectively

```
Event Type  Event Type  ID  Time_Comptel    Distance_Comptel    Fibre Line  Event Date  Event Date
0   Digging Manual Digging  11988339    2019-06-26 12:27:44 444.83  Helios 1012, Channel 2  2019-06-26  2019-06-28
1   Digging Manual Digging  11988337    2019-06-26 12:22:10 447.55  Helios 1012, Channel 2  2019-06-26  2019-06-28
2   Digging Manual Digging  11988336    2019-06-26 12:26:50 446.19  Helios 1012, Channel 2  2019-06-26  2019-06-28
3   Digging Manual Digging  11988335    2019-06-26 12:22:13 447.55  Helios 1012, Channel 2  2019-06-26  2019-06-28
4   Digging Manual Digging  11988334    2019-06-26 12:10:05 446.87  Helios 1012, Channel 2  2019-06-26  2019-06-28


Alarm ID    Event Type  Event Type  Event Date  Event Date  Position    Distance_Tranzmeo   Event Channel   Event Time  Time_Tranzmeo
0   454.0   Digging Manual Digging  2019-06-26  2019-06-28  43.0    0.293   1.0 06:09 am    2019-06-28 06:09:00
1   455.0   Digging Manual Digging  2019-06-26  2019-06-28  2585.0  17.594  1.0 06:09 am    2019-06-28 06:09:00
2   456.0   Digging Manual Digging  2019-06-26  2019-06-28  2585.0  17.594  1.0 06:50 am    2019-06-28 06:50:00
3   457.0   Digging Manual Digging  2019-06-26  2019-06-28  45.0    0.306   1.0 07:04 am    2019-06-28 07:04:00
4   458.0   Digging Manual Digging  2019-06-26  2019-06-28  44.0    0.299   1.0 07:26 am    2019-06-28 07:26:00
```

I like to create another dataframe such that the `Time_Comptel` should be close to `Time_Tranzmeo` (any row, need not be respective rows) (close meaning max differnce between them should be + or - 1 hour and `Distance_Comptel` and `Distance_tranzmeo` should close (+ or - 100) as well.

Join Such rows column wise and append to a dataframe (`df_match`) and rest to another datafame(`df_nomatch`). How is this possible? Sorry I am not yet able to come up with Ideas myself checking respective rows I get but I need to compare every combination.How can it be done.

```
Note: Time_Tranzmeo is the last column in dataframe 2
```

If I have underemphasised sth please let me know in the comments

Comment: Can you share the expected output for this sample ?

Comment: Sorry how can I get the output! I can only get it if I finish the program , manually generating the output is tiresome

Comment: perhaps this might help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33272807/pandas-merge-dataframes-by-closest-time