# Fastest way to create time series dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, time, series

I want to take data that contains time gaps as well as time **repeats** and basically create a time series using the first occurrence of any given time and filling forwards.  Consider the following example.

Lets say this is the time range we are interested in:

| Time |
| --- |
| 1:00 |
| 1:01 |
| 1:02 |
| 1:03 |
| 1:04 |
| 1:05 |

And this is the data, dataframe X, we would like to put into our time series:

| Occurance | Value |
| --- | --- |
| 1:00 | "R" |
| 1:03 | "G" |
| 1:03 | "L" |
| 1:03 | "P" |
| 1:03 | "T" |
| 1:05 | "S" |

And this is the Final Dataframe:

| Occurance | Value |
| --- | --- |
| 1:00 | "R" |
| 1:01 | "R" |
| 1:02 | "R" |
| 1:03 | "G" |
| 1:04 | "G" |
| 1:05 | "S" |

As you can see, in the Final Dataframe, 1:00 has the value "R" because that is the value in the first occurrence of 1:00 in dataframe X.  1:01 and 1:02 also have the value "R" because there is no data for those time instances in dataframe X and will therefore use the last valid value (which is the value for 1:00).  1:03 has the value "G" because, similar to the case with 1:00, "G" is the first value for 1:03 that we have in dataframe X.  Since there is no value for 1:04 in dataframe X, 1:04 gets the last valid value, "G", in our resulting dataframe.  Lastly, 1:05 will have the value "S" in our resulting dataframe as that is the value for the first occurrence of 1:05 in dataframe X.

What is the quickest way to accomplish this?

Comment: Not sure but pandas.merge_asof came to my mind.

Comment: Simplifieds examples are here: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/pandas-merge_asof-function-in-python/  Just think as if  "a" column was timestamp/date  type. See also https://stackoverflow.com/a/44171464/813946

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### `merge_asof`

See **Solution** below to see final solution.

First, we need to change those columns to `pd.Timedelta`:

```
df1['Time'] = pd.to_timedelta(df1['Time'] + ':00')
df2['Occurance'] = pd.to_timedelta(df2['Occurance'] + ':00')
```

Then we can `merge_asof`

```
pd.merge_asof(df1, df2, left_on='Time', right_on='Occurance')

             Time       Occurance Value
0 0 days 01:00:00 0 days 01:00:00     R
1 0 days 01:01:00 0 days 01:00:00     R
2 0 days 01:02:00 0 days 01:00:00     R
3 0 days 01:03:00 0 days 01:03:00     T
4 0 days 01:04:00 0 days 01:03:00     T
5 0 days 01:05:00 0 days 01:05:00     S
```

There are a couple of things wrong with this:

1. There are more columns than OP specified.
2. I have `T`s instead of `G`s

Ok to get rid of the columns, we just rename one of the columns instead of using `left_on`/`right_on`

```
pd.merge_asof(df1.set_axis(['Occurance'], axis=1), df2)

        Occurance Value
0 0 days 01:00:00     R
1 0 days 01:01:00     R
2 0 days 01:02:00     R
3 0 days 01:03:00     T
4 0 days 01:04:00     T
5 0 days 01:05:00     S
```

But we still have `T`s instead of `G`s and that's because look at `df2`

```
        Occurance Value
0 0 days 01:00:00     R
1 0 days 01:03:00     G  # same Occurance
2 0 days 01:03:00     L  # same Occurance
3 0 days 01:03:00     P  # same Occurance
4 0 days 01:03:00     T  # same Occurance
5 0 days 01:05:00     S
```

Obviously, Pandas took the last one while OP wanted first one.  So let's try again with `drop_duplicates`

#### Solution

```
pd.merge_asof(df1.set_axis(['Occurance'], axis=1),
              df2.drop_duplicates('Occurance'))

        Occurance Value
0 0 days 01:00:00     R
1 0 days 01:01:00     R
2 0 days 01:02:00     R
3 0 days 01:03:00     G
4 0 days 01:04:00     G
5 0 days 01:05:00     S
```